# SE's editor should use a Discourse-style layout for side-by-side Markdown preview

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview, user-experience, scrolling

The UX issue of the Markdown preview being under the edit box has been discussed several times:

- [Putting the edit box and the markdown box side by side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249679/putting-the-edit-box-and-the-markdown-box-side-by-side)
- [Synced vertical scrollbar in the markdown preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168307/long-post-edit-and-markdown-preview) (no answer)
- [Preview on the right please, optionally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/preview-on-the-right-please-optionally)
- [Can't see the preview at the bottom of a long post](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/cant-see-the-preview-at-the-bottom-of-a-long-post) (Math.SE)

The answers proposed brought up several counter-arguments to implementing a side-by-side preview:

- "screwing low-res users", along with [statistics of visitor screen size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53486/150034), as of 2010
- "The design of the site is always a single column downward. When anything expands, it expands further downward."
- this could be done via userscripts [NB: I hadn't found any that worked]
- the side panel displays useful information, such as the Similar Questions list

I would like to propose a different solution that's already implemented in SE-inspired discussion software *Discourse* and works very well:

[image: Discourse does it better]

#### Advantages

- tried & tested - Discourse is mature software
- familiarity - Jeff Atwood is/was behind both SE and Discourse
- the code is already available - Discourse is open source
- autoscroll is implemented
- accessible to low-res users as well via the fluid layout. The screencast above is shot at about 1024px width
- preserves the sidebar - you can see related topics in Discourse; SE can display related questions
- the "hide preview" link reverts to a single-column editor, and could place the preview under it, to replicate the current layout

For those who want to make sure they [avoid horizontal scrollbars in code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70703/question-and-preview-might-be-better-side-by-side/70708#70708), the preview area could be sized by default to the current preview size, and a divider between the editor and the preview (just as Discourse has one between the editor+preview and the posts area) could allow further control over the editor vs. preview width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview on the right please, optionally?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/preview-on-the-right-please-optionally)

Comment: @TylerH: As you [can see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/preview-on-the-right-please-optionally#comment826609_53506), I was aware of that question before posting mine.

Answer (score 7):

I've tweaked and added to [ˈjuː.zɚ79365's version](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/cant-see-the-preview-at-the-bottom-of-a-long-post/9841#9841) of a side-by-side editing script from Mathematics.SE to make it work again. It's in a userscript format.

### [Side by Side editing @ Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/6461/26088)

[image: example image]

For more information and an installation link, please visit my [Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/6461/26088) :)

This script **does not**, unlike Discourse, have autoscroll, and does not preserve the sidebar.

It just about fits side-by-side on my 1366 x 768 monitor, so I'd say that's the minimum size you should have...

---

### Note: I have also added this feature to my [SE Additional Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) (as of v1.5).

Install it to get this feature and many more all collated into one big userscript - all options are *optional*! See the [Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) for more info on installation.

Comment: How can we implement or use this for all StackExchange sites? Can users put something in their browsers?

Comment: @AlexS if you follow the link to my 'SE Additional Optional Features' script - you will see the 'Installation and Requirements' section - over there, it tells you how you can install this userscript :) Feel free to comment over there if you're having trouble installing it! :)

Comment: ( @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ suggestion: in the SOX userscript, for the feature search, adding `preview` as a search keyword for this feature.  PS: Your userscript is awesome – thank you so much for this invaluable contribution!!♥♥)

Comment: @AaronThoma Thanks for the suggestion! I'll add that in for the next DEV version :)) I'm really glad you find the userscript so useful! :D (edit: done in v2.6.22 dev! :)

Answer (score 5):

I would also really like to see this implemented. Media queries are one way to do it, but I would be satisfied with a user setting that just enables side-by-side editing and Markdown output. If the setting for side-by-side it true then just use half the page split vertically for each regardless of the window width. I always preview my writing and fix any errors. Scrolling back up to the edit area and back down to the preview a dozen times or more is a big hassle.